# Create and register C# COM Dll

Tags: c#, com

I am trying to learn how to  create and register a COM DLL using VS2017 C#.
For this purpose, I wrote test code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace ComObject1
{
    [ProgId("ComObject1.ClassExample")]
    [Guid("e514c7d2-ed6d-44c6-a7e2-36a272a8ba76")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class ClassExample
    {
        [ComVisible(true)]
        public string Mystring()
        {

            return "Hello, world!";
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I registered my DLL with regasm.exe and tried to use it with Excel:

```
Sub Test()

Dim testClass As New COM_Dll.ClassExample
Dim Res As String
Res = testClass.Mystring()    

End Sub
```

Sad, but I have a run-time

> error 429 (activex component can't create object).

...hence, Excel "can not see"  Mystring() method. What I am doing wrong?
P.S. when I add my DLL to C# app as class library (not COM), it works:

```
 var c = new ComObject1.ClassExample();
    Console.WriteLine(c.Mystring());
```

Now, I changed code a little (by another manual)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace COM_Dll
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("4945B34B-1B63-4a58-B5FE-9627FEFAEA9D")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    public interface IInterface01
    {       
        string Mystring(string s);

    }

    [ComVisible(true)] 
    [Guid("36E6BC94-308C-4952-84E6-109041990EF7")]
    [ProgId("COM_Dll.CSCOMClass01")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class CSCOMClass01 : IInterface01
    {                

        public string Mystring(string s)
        {
            return "test";
        }

    }
}
```

Now, I can add method Mystring() in EXCEL,  but "error 429 (activex component can't create object)" still present if I run macro.

[image]

Comment: Your regasm.exe command was not correct.  Don't expect SO users to write you a manual, it has already been written, show us what you typed.  And you must mention what kind of Office flavor you have installed, the distinction between the 32-bit and 64-bit edition is important.

Comment: Most likely caused by 32 bit Excel and `Any CPU`-built .NET DLL on 64 bit Windows.  Please confirm

Comment: When use regasm I just type regasm.exe [path-to-dll]. Also, I tried to add key /codebase My MS Office version is 2016 x64, windows 10 x64. When I add reference to dll, EXCEL has no any error and intellisence can see namespase and class. It cannot see method Mystring() for some reason..

Comment: Now, I changed code a little (by other manual)

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in conflict of namespaces. If you register COM Dll, you shall be convinced, that there is no namespace/class/signature conflict. It is important to be careful, if you build Dll with "Register for COM interop" option - because your test builds may leave "trash" in registry.